# Finding files with specific range and moving the files

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a script to find files with naming convention as below:-

```
F_XYZ_1_2020.xml
F_XYZ_2_2020.xml
F_XYZ_3_2020.xml
F_XYZ_4_2020.xml
F_XYZ_5_2020.xml
....
F_XYZ_221_2020.xml
```

I am looking to create a script which finds all the files before F_XYZ_221_2020.xml and then move it to /destination/

I tried

```
ls -lrt | grep -v 'F_XYZ_221_' | mv * /destination/
```

It is not working for me.

Comment: _It is not working for me_ is not an accurate description of your problem. Please edit your question and explain what's wrong with your first attempt.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/
http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/
Check the [`mv` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1p.html) (c.f.). `mv` doesn't read listd of files from `stdin`, though it's possible to use `xargs` for that...but you don't need that here. `mv F_XYZ_{1..221}_2020.xml /destination/` is the syntax for your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a range operator.

```
mv F_XYZ_{1..221}_2020.xml /destination/
```